# Filling DateTime with both date and time

Tags: vb6

I can construct a new DateTime with year, month and day by using DateSerial, and I can construct a new DateTime with hour, minute and second by using TimeSerial, but I haven't found out yet how I could do both at the same time.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: please show the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` type already holds: Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute and Second.

In fact, both `DateSerial` and `TimeSerial` return a variant of type `Date`.

You can create a "complete" datetime with:

`MyDate = DateValue("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")`